# On Windows 7, how can I disable Putty Security Alert dialog pop up when connecting to EC2 VM?

Tags: command-line

I'm using EC2 as a server and want to automatically run some batch files to set up , but the alert dialog just blocked my batch files, anybody know how to disable the alert dialog?

the alert dialog is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manually log in to those servers using Putty, click the "Yes" button on that dialog, Putty will cache the server key so those dialogs will not pop up on subsequent connections (unless you reinstall ssh on the server or change the server's key)

You can use plink, a command-line version of Putty, that should not pop-up these dialogs (or use openssh) I haven't used plink.

Comment: I tried the plink and it works. really cool. thanks a lot.